# Can I use Report Builder 2016 to create reports using SSRS 2014?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

Sorry for such a basic question, but google didn't clear up anything. 
Can I use Report Builder 2016 if I have SQL Server Report Service 2014?
Is it compatible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Report Builder 2016. But if your **report server** is an earlier version, you'll need to set the **TargetServerVersion** to **SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012 or 2014**.

The TargetServerVersion property is in DEBUG --> Reporting Properties in Visual Studio but I don't remember where it is in Report Builder but it should be similar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Report Builder 2016 to build your reports. Report Builder will accept 2014 databases as a data source.